Is "deep lookup operator" for map implemented in any XQJ processor?
https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xquery-40/xquery-40.html#id-deep-lookup educates about deep lookup operator for maps and arrays. Although BaseX and Saxon XQJ processors implement this Xquery 4.0 (even though it is in draft status), this deep lookup operator for maps and arrays is not implemented there. Does anyone know which XQJ processor (if any) implements this deep lookup operation for maps and arrays ?
Tried using deep lookup for maps and arrays in BaseX and Saxon, but it doesn't seem to be supported.

I am not sure there is any public release of either Saxon or BaseX already implementing that stuff. Michael Kay demoed it with Saxon EE 13 (development build, I suppose) at XmlPrague, I think, but there has been no effort to include it in a public release as the work is ongoing both in terms of spec and implementations.

We have implemented this but not yet released it. We're holding back new QT4.0 features at the moment until SaxonJ 13 comes out. The spec on this is still in flux.

Thanks for the information Michael. I'll look forward for SaxonJ 13.
